# CentOS guest does not boot anymore after Virtualbox encryption

Tags: boot, virtualbox, encryption, centos-7

I installed a CentOS 7 VM with VirtualBox and it ran perfectly fine.
Then I activated image-encryption in VirtualBox for that Guest and started to boot. The grub2 screen shows up correctly but when I try to boot any configuration, the emergency mode shows up.

After turning of the encryption, the system boots fine again.
Looking at the journal I could see that it could not find vmlinuz images and the boot-folder is completely empty. So I reinstalled the kernel, created a initramfs and run grub2-mkconfig to try to get it working again, but that did not solve it.
Strange thing is, that it starts to work right after I decrypted the image again.

I couldn't find too much information about how the encryption really works (for me it would make sense to encrypt the whole vb-image-file with all the partitions within it), so can it be that just parts of the system will be encrypted and that the system cant't find them anymore?
That won't make much sense, but I've seen strange things before.

Let me know if you need any logs or something like it.